# Using the Adsense management API how do I get the exact URL in which each ad was shown when I generate a report?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, single-page-application, adsense-api

## What I need to do:

I want to generate adsense reports programmatically to get the earnings and the page views for each ad in my website that lets users post their own articles, so I need to know from which URL the earning comes from to be able to share the revenue with the users, and show them their statistics.

## What I tried:

I went to the API, and found [reports.generate](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.4/reference/accounts/reports/generate), which seems to do what I want, so I tried it in their "API Explorer" to see what kind of data was available, and in the [Metrics and Dimensions page](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/metrics-dimensions), I found these parameters that seemed to do what I wanted:

> **Dimensions**: DATE, URL_CHANNEL_NAME
>   **Metrics**: EARNINGS, PAGE_VIEWS

EARNINGS, PAGE_VIEWS, and DATE work as expected, but URL_CHANNEL_NAME only gives me the base URL of the website, not the URL of the page in which the ad is shown that I would need.

For example, if my website is `https://stackoverflow.com` and I show ads on `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/somePostUniqueID` I'd like to see the latter in the reports, but I only see `https://stackoverflow.com`.

So, instead of `URL_CHANNEL_NAME` I also tried:

`URL_CHANNEL_ID`: Same as `URL_CHANNEL_NAME`, but with the `accountId` prepended to it, which I don't need, since it's the same for every URL.

`DOMAIN_NAME`: Also just gives the base domain, without the specific URL

`CUSTOM_CHANNEL_NAME`: Seems that I can only add these manually, and they're limited to 50, so probably not what I want in this case.

And the rest of them don't seem to be relevant to my problem.

The posts on my site are generated dynamically from the URL, so I'm worried that the ad is not able to read the URL properly to send it back to the reports, could this be the case?

The website is made with Angular 5, and when clicking a link formatted like this:

`sitename.com/posts/uniquePostURL`

The `uniquePostURL` is parsed, and the matching article is loaded, so it takes a while for the content to load, and the base page in which the ad is is actually just `sitename.com/posts`, and since in the reports I see both `sitename.com` and `sitename.com/posts` when using `URL_CHANNEL_NAME`, I'm worried that might be the reason.

Any idea if that is actually the reason, or if that's fine and I'm doing something else wrong?

Thank you.